# Import doesn't work using other intermediary module

Tags: python

I am trying to import a module via another module. My code is as the following:
**main.py**

```
import init
myInsert = Insert()
```

**init.py**

```
from insert import Insert
```

**insert.py**

```
class Insert:
  def __init__(self):
    print('insert is innitiated')<br>
```

It means that i am trying to have an init file to load all modules I need for later times.
For example I am trying to load `insert` module by `init` module and then use it in `main.py`.
Unfortunately an error occures when I run `main.py` which is as followes:

```
NameError: name 'Insert' is not defined
```

Could you please tell me what am i doing wrong and how to make it work?

Comment: Try to change `myInsert = Insert()` with `myInsert = init.Insert()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
import init
myInsert = Insert()
```

The name `Insert` is indeed not defined. Where does it come from? Not from `init`, because names that come from that module would be referenced as `init.name`, so it must be global. But it's not defined anywhere else (there's no assignment like `Init = <thing>`, no star imports like `from init import *`), so here's an error.

You're looking for:

```
myInsert = init.Insert()
```

Comment: Thak you very much. I had not noticed it and I learned something new right now. Using `from init import *` also worked and it worked beautifully. Good luck.